# How do you summon mobs to dropped items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I summon a mob at the same place as a dropped item? I tried /summon Zombie @e[type=Ingot.iron] but I couldn't get it to work.

Also, is it possible to summon mobs to a named item, e.g. an iron ingot named "Zombie"?

Answer (score 5):

`/summon` doesn't take a a target to summon the mob at, so you'll need to use `/execute`, and selectors can't select items by type, so you'll need to use `/scoreboard players set` (which can set a score for items with specific NBT data) to set the entity's score first, and then select it based on that scoreboard objective.

First, set up a dummy scoreboard objective that we will use to keep track of items that are iron ingots:

```
/scoreboard objectives add isIronIngot dummy
```

Then run this on a clock, to set all dropped iron ingot's `isIronIngot` score to 1:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] isIronIngot 1 {Item:{id:"minecraft:iron_ingot"}}
```

Now, whenever you want to spawn a zombie at the iron ingots, use this command:

```
/execute @e[score_isIronIngot_min=1] ~ ~ ~ /summon Zombie
```

Which will make anything with an isIronIngot score of (at least) 1 summon a zombie.

To have this only work with ingots named "Zombie", replace the second command with:

```
/scoreboard players set @e[type=Item] isIronIngot 1 {Item:{id:"minecraft:iron_ingot",tag:{display:{Name:"Zombie"}}}}
```

Comment: Thx ill try this out next time im online i hope it gos well cuz im designing a blaze turret when u drop the ingot it summons the turret which is a custom blaze

Answer (score 1):

I feel that there is definitely an easier way:

> /execute @e[type=Item] ~ ~ ~ summon Zombie ~ ~ ~

It should work, just the only downside is that /execute cannot support NBT's like {Item:{id:"minecraft:iron_ingot"}}

Comment: I Managed It Kinda, But Only To Non Named Items I Gave Up On That And Started Using Spawn Eggs Functions eg.

Comment: /execute @e[type=Zombie,name=FireBall] ~ ~1 ~ /summon Fireball ~ ~ ~ {direction:[],ExplosionPower:3] It Works :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following command:

```
/entitydata @e[type=Item,c=1] {CustomName:"ironIngot"}
```

to give the item a name. (`ironIngot` is only an example)

Then you use this command:

```
/execute @e[name=ironIngot] ~ ~ ~ summon Zombie ~ ~ ~ {}
```

to summon the zombie.

I left the brackets empty to indicate that you could give tags to the zombie to customise it